# Compare 2 ActiveRecord Relations rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an `interest form` which is used to add an interest to a user. The structure of the database is as follows:

`Users - id ...`

`Interests - id ..`

`UsersMapInterests - user_id interest_id`

So when a user selects an interest from the `Interests` table, it gets added to the `UsersMapInterests` table.

A query for user 1 would return something like `{{user_id: 1, interest_id 3},{user_id: 1, interest_id 7},{user_id: 1, interest_id 25}}`.

A query for user 22 would return `{user_id: 22, interest_id 3},{user_id: 22, interest_id 3}`

Now I would like to compare the results with each other.

I assume that using `to_a` and comparing them like this would be too much:

```
user1.each do |int1|
      user22.each do |int2|
        if int1.interest_id == int2.interest_id
          count++
        end
      end
    end
```

How else could I compare them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use the following line of code

```
(user1.interest_ids & user22.interest_ids).count
```

Explanation:

```
user1.interest_ids
#=> [3, 7, 25]

user22.interest_ids
#=> [3, 3]

[3, 7, 25] & [3, 3] # Returns common element from both arrays
#=> [3]

[3].count
#=> 1
```

Comment: It will return you the common interest ids in both

Comment: Is that like an intersection?

Comment: Ok, I see from your edit not. So it is an intersection. I had no idea I could do this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I will do something like this:

```
user1_interest_ids = user1.map { |o| o[:interest_id] }
user22_interest_ids = user22.map { |o| o[:interest_id] }

count = (user1_interest_ids & user22_interest_ids).size
```